# Calling a RESTful API and parsing XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am calling a RESTful API and getting the XML response below which I am attempting to parse in Python (apologies in advance for the screenshot - could not get the formatting to work). There are multiple 'entry' nodes.

I have imported the raw XML into an (c)elementree object:

> doc = ET.fromstring(xml_raw)

And then extract all of the 'entry' nodes by:

> doc.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry')

How do I find these nodes without writing '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}'? What is this and where does it come from (its not in the node text/values in the raw XML)?

Thanks in advance for any help[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think You can do this without namespace( at least not with `ElementTree`)

XML Namespaces provide a method to avoid element name conflicts.
One can have two similar tags in different namespaces.
this namespace in `xmlns` attribute of `feed` tag